# How to embed mjpeg file on a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming

I got the requirement to display output from an IP camera to the webpage so end users can use this page to view live from this camera.

It has an interface which provides .mjpeg output for captured video, I need to embed this on my webpage. It should work on Firefox, Safari and IE at-least.

Thanks in advance

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: All IP cameras I've seen use either ActiveX or java controls, but I'd expect Flash would work too. Have you tried googling "MJPEG Flash" etc.? I don't think the signal / noise is very high but there must be some leads there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis Camera itself has a control panel like interface, from there you can find a code (which is javascript at the end) that actually includes an ActiveX control on page and does the rest.

So far this solution worked for me and client is agreed with the installation required on client side for this ActiveX.

thanks for the reply @Rup

Comment: But for MJPEG you dont need to have ActiveX control. You just need to put MJPEG address to SRC attribute of <img> ilke so: `<img src="http://192.168.0.101/mjpg/video.mjpg"/>`

Comment: MSIE does not play MJPEG in <img/> tag. (Android stock browser neither does.)