# How can I detect whether a browser supports MJPEG?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, browser-feature-detection

Modern browsers except IE handle `MJPEG` ([Motion JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sGfs7/16/) is an example fiddle.

Can I detect support for `MJPEG`? I have looked through [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the most obvious way to detect if the image could be loaded or not:

```
$output = $('<img id="webcam">')
        .attr('src', src)
        .load(function(){alert('ok')})
        .error(function(){alert('error')});
```

In case image could be loaded `load` event will be fired, otherwise `error`. Checked this in recent Chrome and IE8. Works as expected.

Comment: This doesn't work on Android web browsers.  At least on two different Samsung phones, the default Android browser neither shows the MJPEG, nor fires a load or error event -- it tries to load the "whole" stream without rendering it.

Answer (score 4):

[Modernizr only supports the following formats for detection right now: ogg, webm and h264.](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5)

The video element has a call called `canPlayType(format)` that would really be your only option (if it works for mjpg).  Your detection logic would look something like this (not the format would be different).

```
var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
if(!!videoElement.canPlayType)
{
  var browserConfidence = videoElement.canPlayType('video/mjpeg; codecs="insert, them"');
  if(browserConfidence == "probably")
  {
    // high confidence
  }
  else if(browserConfidence == "maybe")
  {
    // low confidence
  }
  else
  {
    // no confidence... it definately will not play
  }
}
```

Make sure you [visit the W3C's information on canPlayType](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype).  It looks like the mime type should be "video/mjpeg" and not "video/mjpg" as you specified earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly for this you would need to use an ActiveX control to support mjpg in IE. See [How to embed mjpeg file on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307418/how-to-embed-mjpeg-file-on-a-webpage).